# Directory problems when using permalinks in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks

I am running into a problem when coding a theme.
My wordpress folder lives in public_html/
The permaline setting is set to "Post name", so it is something like http://websiteurl.com/post-name/

In my theme, I want to load an image that lives in public_html/media/, but when I use

```
<img src="media/img.jpg">
```

the browser tries to find the image in the folder public_html/post-name/media/img.jpg. How should I code my theme so this does not happen? I don't want to change my permalink option to ?page=ID.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It will better to use full absolute path like

```
<img src="http://websiteurl.com/media/img.jpg">
```

. So it will not create issue when your path will 
http://websiteurl.com/category/post-name/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<img src="/media/img.jpg">
```

instead.  The first `/` will make the browser start looking under `public_html` instead of under `post-name`.